# SQL Query for search on column (Help in SQL query)

Tags: mysql, sql

how are you i need help in somthing

i need MYsql query to search in column for row that have value with 9 digit

like below

if table

```
degree
1
22
1
345
43
234
555
```

select where have digit 3 number 
so he pick 
345  and 234 and 555

Comment: What is the data type of degree?

Answer (score 1):

If the column is of string datatype, use the `REGEXP` operator:

```
select * from mytable where degree REGEXP '^[0-9]{3}$'
```

If it's an integer column, then just do number comparisons:

```
select * from mytable where degree between 100 and 999
```

Comment: Numbers only and i need it pick not between higher and lower i need it pick by column width or like how many digits in the columns

Comment: like pick that have 6 digits in it

Comment: if it 00  000 000 00 0 00

Comment: it pick the 3 digits 000 and 000

Comment: @Sarah: what is the *datatype* of column `degree` in your table?

Comment: digit 20 numbers

Comment: @Sarah: `digit` is not a datatype. If you have things like `000`, `00`, then this looks like some `varchar` column (if it was something like `integer`, then it would just be `0`).

Comment: not 0 i give example like lets say i have table have data with 100 million record there is column name bounce with numbers users input i need to select all who wrote code with 6 digits to appear random like if u type 1 11 21 43 7777 71 26  i will need to select any number that have 2 digits so it select 11 21 43 71 26 i donot wana between or > <  i need  numbers that is odd of even or all numbers that have 6 digits or have 9 digits

Answer (score 0):

If the values are numbers you can use:

```
where degree >= 100 and degree < 1000
```

If `degree` is a string that only contains digits:

```
where degree like '___'
```

If `degree` is a string that can contain non-digits:

```
where degree regexp '^[0-9]{3}$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple query to search for numbers between 100 and 999:

```
select  *
  from  mytable
  where degree >= 100 AND degree < 1000
```